# PHP grep file contents from url

Tags: php

So I'm a little puzzled and wondering if someone could help me out. I'm in need to grep the outs of this file contents by URL which is returned.  What I get returned is:

```
{"level":30,"pic":"http:\/\/ddragon.leagueoflegends.com\/cdn\/5.23.1\/img\/profileicon\/716.png","wins":5,"games":{"1":{"champ":412,"outcome":false,"kills":3,"deaths":13,"assists":15},"2":{"champ":53,"outcome":false,"kills":1,"deaths":11,"assists":5},"3":{"champ":91,"outcome":false,"kills":4,"deaths":10,"assists":2},"4":{"champ":67,"outcome":false,"kills":2,"deaths":6,"assists":4}}}
```

What i want to grep is firstly the value under level in this case "30", then profileicon716.png (without the weird /) then the champ value without the ':' for the first game, wins of the first game, the outcome (true or false without the :), kills, deaths and assists (just the value) of each game (there are 4 total). I need to take each value and assign it to a string dependant on each game, i.e. $killsgames1 = 3

As you can tell it's pretty difficult hence why I'm coming over here for help. I usually like to solve these matters myself rather than get spoon fed but this is just too mind boggling for me.

Comment: It's actually much simpler than you think, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and you're pretty much good to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to grep or parse, it's JSON:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);

echo $array['level'];
echo basename($array['pic']);

foreach($array['games'] as $game) {
    echo $game['champ'];
    //etc...
}
```

Do a `print_r($array);` to see the structure.

Also, no need to assign to other variables, they are already in a usable format such as:

```
$array['games'][0]['kills']
$array['games'][1]['kills']
$array['games'][2]['kills']
//etc...
```

Comment: Very nice thanks so much! What about for searching for an value in an array and returning another, i.e. search for 3 kills and return the outcome (in this case it would be false as the game was lost)

Comment: Post that as another question, and be more descriptive as I don't know what you mean.